# Why is my JavaScript hoisted local variable returning undefined but the hoisted global variable is returning blank?

Tags: javascript, undefined, hoisting

As part of my learning JavaScript, I try to write code to demonstrate the concept I am learning; today I'm learning hoisted variables.  Here is the code I wrote:

```
console.log("A: My name is " + name);   

function happy() {
  console.log ("1: I am " + feeling);   
    var feeling = "happy";
  console.log ("2: I am " + feeling);   
}
happy(); 

var name = "Jim";
console.log("B: My name is " + name);
```

I expected the following results:

```
A: My name is undefined
1: I am undefined
2: I am happy
B: My name is Jim
```

However, when testing my code at WriteCodeOnline.com and in another sandbox, the first console.log displays `A: My name is`. I am using a Chrome browser, if that makes a difference.

So, my question is, why does the hoisted local variable within the function return undefined while the hoisted global variable returns a blank?

Comment: It does appear that another question exists that answers my question. Had I known the answer to my question, I probably would have been able to find the other question as well. I have no problem if this question is closed.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

What is happening here is that you are accessing [window.name](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window.name).

This is a predefined property on `window`, so your hoisted `var name` isn't actually creating a new variable. There's already one in the global scope with that name and by default, it has a blank string value.

To observe the behavior you were expecting, you can use a variable name other than `name`, or put your code inside a function:

```js
function hoisting() {
  console.log("A: My name is " + name);   

  function happy() {
    console.log ("1: I am " + feeling);   
    var feeling = "happy";
    console.log ("2: I am " + feeling);   
  }
  happy(); 

  var name = "Jim";
  console.log("B: My name is " + name);   
}

hoisting();
```

Comment: Well, it's good to know my expectations were right. Now back to learning that keywords, etc. can't be used as variable names.

Comment: @JimLockwood The important takeaway here is to keep your identifiers out of the global scope. :)

Comment: @RobG Don't you mean `"name" in window`?

Comment: @RobG `console.log(typeof name);
console.log("name" in window);` prints out `string true`. The standards creators don't tend to  leave creation of standard `window` properties up to the user.

Comment: @JLRishe—perhaps that's why it's an empty string until a user sets it to some other value.