# Can't get global variables inside the function (javascript)

Tags: javascript, variables, global

```
var selection = document.getElementById('selection');
var closed = true;

function openorclosebar() {

    if(closed == false){
        selection.style.webkitAnimation='bounceOutDown 1s forwards';
        selection.style.animation='bounceOutDown 1s forwards';
        closed = false;
    }
    else{
        selection.style.webkitAnimation='bounceInUp 1s forwards';
        selection.style.animation='bounceInUp 1s forwards';
        closed = true;
    };
}
```

How can I get global variables "selection" and "closed" to use them. I tried "window.selection" and "window.closed", but nothing helps. If you have an idea, help me please, it's so important project.

Comment: The code you have inside `openorclosebar` will successfully access the variables you declared outside the function. You are probably misdiagnosing the problem (I expect that `selection` doesn't hold the value you think it should hold)

Comment: And what can I do now?

Comment: `if (close == false){ close = false }` something wrong here ?

Comment: I've corrected it but nothing changes.

Comment: @SargisAndreyan — You can try to identify what you actual problem is, but looking at what the values are, considering timing, and providing more code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [global `closed` variable](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window.closed) is read-only: It's the `window`s `.closed` property - such [has happened before with `.name`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/27713457/1048572) :-)

Use an IEFE to make your variable local:

```
(function() {
    var selection = document.getElementById('selection');
    var closed = true;

    function openorclosebar() {
        if(!closed) {
            selection.style.webkitAnimation='bounceOutDown 1s forwards';
            selection.style.animation='bounceOutDown 1s forwards';
            closed = false;
        } else {
            selection.style.webkitAnimation='bounceInUp 1s forwards';
            selection.style.animation='bounceInUp 1s forwards';
            closed = true;
        }
    }
}());
```

Also have a look at [other unsafe names](http://jibbering.com/faq/names/) in browser environments.